# While loop not working as expected. Code is not fully executed

Tags: c

I have started a course for C programming and i have to build a program which counts characters that you input. It should count A-Z,0-9,a-z. I made this program as seen below and in the attached screenshot but i am unable to type more than one character. 
As you can see i tried first to make the loop go for numbers but after the first input it will not go to the next 'scanf'.

https://i.gyazo.com/5fcc0d90688f2e27970506fd999a2c4b.png

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char input;
int contorMAJ = 0, contorMIN = 0 , contorNR =0;

printf("Type a character(0-9,a-z,A-Z): ");
scanf("%c",&input);




while(input>=48 && input<=57 || input >= 65 && input <= 90 || input >= 97 && input <= 122 )
{
    if(input>=48 && input<=57)
    {
        printf("Type another character(0-9,a-z,A-Z): ");
        contorNR++;
        scanf("%c",&input);
    }

}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the `return` statement as mentioned in nicomp's answer, the character scan will include the new-line character (with ASCII code 10), which will make your control condition false after you have typed 2 + Enter.

Comment: Debugger................................

Answer (score 2):

You have a return statement in the while loop. Should it be under the while loop? You will get only one pass through the loop.

Comment: Yea that was dumb of me. Updated code https://i.gyazo.com/5fcc0d90688f2e27970506fd999a2c4b.png

Comment: @CodreanuGeorge Sometimes all it takes is another set of eyes. That's part of programming, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
   //#include<conio.h>
   int main()
    {


      char input,x;
      int contorMAJ = 0, contorMIN = 0 , contorNR =0;

      printf("Type a character(0-9,a-z,A-Z): ");
      //scanf("%c",&input);
      input=getchar();



      while(input>=48 && input<=57 || input >= 65 && input <= 90 || input >= 97 && input <= 122 )
      {

        getchar();
      // scanf("%c",&x);
       if(input>=48 && input<=57)
        {
          printf("Type another character(0-9,a-z,A-Z): ");

            contorNR++;

        }

        input=getchar();
       //scanf("%c",&input);


   }
   return 0;//`enter code here`
 }
```

Updated the code

the mistake is like this

1- When you read first character from keyboard and press enter `\n` is goes into the input

2- As with `\n` conditions are not getting satisfied

3- so use one more `getchar()` to get `\n` in that as updated in the code.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly. But if i can ask you, when \n goes into the input does it change the value of the variable? I dont really understand why it would not respect the conditions. I tried a fast test and entered 2 as a char and when i displayed it as an integer it was still 50 (ascii code for 2).  https://gyazo.com/c7bc4543ab0e5ecbcdcf598ae358548a

Comment: First time you read character in `input` and press enter ....as you press the `enter key ` ...`input` variable contain `\n` ...as `input` contain `\n` the condition in while loop gets fail ...and program move out of for `loop` .....

Comment: For first time it gives the right as you have given in example .....but in a loop the flow runs fast ...that's why `\n` goes into `input` next time.